# Why can't the selenium WebDriver click on anything, even if the element exists and is on focus?

Tags: java, html, selenium

I have a problem with Selenium again.

It was (and I swear!) working a week ago without problems. Today I wanted to write some more tests, but I have an extremely weird problem.

Whenever I want to click on something, Selenium simply doesn't click. With the Firefox-Driver I can even see that the object I want to click is focused, but it happens... nothing.
It happens in IE as in FF, but in IE there are even more errors.

My test breaks in the next step, I do not even get any error-messages for the not-working click.

Also, as mentioned above, I have more errors/bugs with the IE-Driver. The FF-Driver does not click on CERTAIN links (sometimes it works, sometimes not, structure of the link that should be clicked and the code that clicks are equal between the links. Everything is reproducable, but I do not know on what it depends if he clicks it or not, the FF is just behaving the same way every time). The IE-Driver clicks on nothing.

I don't get what I am doing wrong and I invested more than 8 hours into this problem and tried to click those damn links in any way you could think of. Nothing. No errors, not a single step forward.

An example:
The specific HTML-Element:

```
<div id="search">
<form id="keytyp" onsubmit="return false;" target="ECS_GF_CENTER_BOTTOM" method="get" name="keytyp" action="keySearchResult.jsp;jsessionid=F90D1D4731343BF3EB03EACD56CF4314">
    <input type="text" value="Suchbegriff" onkeyup="javascript:startSearchOnReturn(event);" onfocus="this.select()" name="searchString" size="25"></input>
    <div style="float:right;width:20px;">
        <a border="0" href="javascript:search()">
            <img title="Suche nach Begriffen" alt="startSearch" src="images/arrow3.gif"></img>
        </a>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

This snippet represents the "search"-bar in our project. Please keep in mind that this is one of many examples. The error must not be searched here.

What I want to do is to simply click on the a-link. I am trying to do this with the following code:

```
@When("the user searches for the term (.*)")
public void searchForTerm(final String term) throws InterruptedException {
    // Switch back to root-frame
    webdriver.switchTo().defaultContent();

    webdriver.switchTo().frame("start");

    WebElement searchField = webdriver.findElement(By.name("searchString"));
    searchField.clear();
    searchField.sendKeys(term);

    WebElement target = webdriver.findElement(By.id("search")).findElements(By.tagName("a")).get(0);

    target.click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
}
```

As I said, I tried to click on something in so goddamn many ways.

What am I doing wrong here? I really do not know what to do.

Thanks in advance, Guys.

P.S. Yes, I do not have ANY information about what is going wrong as selenium does not tell me anything. It simply does not perform the click.

EDIT: I know this thread is dead, but maybe someone will find this in the future, thinking the issue still remains unfixed. That is not the case.
Actually everything was caused by a misbehaving Tomcat, which was only misbehaving on my machine, I did not had the idea to try accessing the webpage without selenium, because my coworkers were able to do, what they had to do, so I was not actually searching for the error in Tomcat! I do not know why, but when launched on my local system, the Tomcat does not perform any POST-Request or anything. This caused me to think that Selenium was not able to click things, but actually the Tomcat did not respond to these requests in a really weird way. He just ignored the click.
We now set up a server in our local network to run all our tests against this system, so everything is reproducable by every team-member.

Thanks for the tips and ideas by you guys!

Comment: Did you tried to click the image instead of the anchor?

Comment: Yes, of course. I tried to click the link, the image, I tried to submit() the whole form, I tried to submit() the input-field, nothing works.

Comment: Try the following : `WebElement target = webdriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#search a"));`

Comment: The ggod thing on computerprograms is, that they are normally deterministic. If it worked a week ago, there must be a change, either you upgraded your selenium-version, driver-version or someone change the application under test. Can you figure out what happend?

Comment: did you tried to click twice? I had once an Issue with Ie and the cause was, that an ajax-call opened a popup ("please wait...") for a few milliseconds (nearly not visible), but so everytime the browser lost focus. So i needed to click twice nearly everytime, because the first click just gave back the focus to the browserwindow.

Comment: I now tried to click twice, no change. I also tried to call the "search()"-function directly, which brought me a very useful "JS ERROR"...
I now also have to worry about the problem that it actually is NOT deterministic. At least it seems like that.
I have a test, which is first logging the user in successfully and then unsuccessfully. I made a little "study" where I found that the user is logged in successfully 13 out of 20 times, using the same code and the same webdriver (FF). 7 times it was unsuccessfully due to not repoducable behaviour.

Comment: It's really hard to guess without seeing the application. But everytime I had such "sometimes successful and sometimes not"-issues, it was always a timing Problem and and explicite wait was helpful. Waiting for Ajax to be ready, waiting for a special element to be visible...etc.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Without seeing an application it could be everything. Thank you anyways! I thought that I maybe missed something in the syntax or anything.
I have a meeting with some of the seniors in a few days and they will take a look at it!

Answer (score 0):

Did Webdriver throw any exception to you? It is really hard to investigate an issue without any stack trace of error. 
Your code:
`WebElement target = webdriver.findElement(By.id("search")).findElements(By.tagName("a")).get(0);` can cause a several problems:

1. The list of elements with tagName="a" can be empty.
2. The target element may be not fully loaded on the page.

Possible solutions:
You can try to use any other element attributes to check whether element is accesible.

Also you can try to use WebdriverWait `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("search")));` before initializing 'target' variable.

BDD framework also can cause some issues to your tests.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. No, I do not have any stacktrace as Selenium is just doing nothing, my test fails in the next step, where the (not existing) search-results should be verified. To answer your question of the list and things, in FF I am actually seeing a dotted line around the link/image, so selenium knows what it has to click. Wouldn't I get a Nullpointer-Exception if the list was empty? Also the wait is not needed, the webdriver already has an implicit-wait of 20 seconds.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay with answer. I have an experience, when Implicit Wait is not work as expected - so Explicit wait should be used (just for investigation). Also you can try to rewrite your test without bdd framework and see if error is appeared again. Try to play with simple Thread.sleep() before - after te line where test fails - in order to investigate whether your problem with waits or in something else. (Of course you should not use Thread.sleep() in your real test code).

Comment: Hi there,

I "fixed" it. It was a misbehaving (I still don't know why) Tomcat, which is only misbehaving in a special environment. My PC.

I am now testing against a VM in the local network and everything works good so far (except for unstable response-times, what sucks with explicit waits). See the edit in the start-post for more info. Anyways, thanks for your help.